# Nodejs createCipheriv like openssl

Tags: node.js, encryption, openssl, cryptography, mariadb

MariaDB's encryption at rest relies on openssl's sha1 encryption of a keys.txt file (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/encryption-key-management/#encrypting-the-key-file). I need to start a MariaDB instance using Node.js. So, I need to encrypt this file in a similar way using Node.js. So far, using https://github.com/beeven/gulp-openssl-encrypt as a guide, I've been able to replicate openssl's version of `-md md5`. But that's not the sha1 digest required by MariaDB.

```
function md5(data) {
  let hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
  hash.update(data);
  return hash.digest();
}
const buffer = Buffer.from(stringToEncrypt);
const salt = crypto.randomBytes(8);
const password = Buffer.from(encryptionKey);
const hash1 = md5(Buffer.concat([password, salt]));
const hash2 = md5(Buffer.concat([hash1, password, salt]));
const key = Buffer.concat([hash1, hash2]);
const iv = md5(Buffer.concat([hash2, password, salt]));
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
const chunks = [Buffer.from('Salted__'),salt];
chunks.push(cipher.update(buffer));
chunks.push(cipher.final());
let encryptedStuff = Buffer.concat(chunks);
```

(Edit: Clarification) What I would like is something like this:

```
function sha1(data) {
  let hash = crypto.createHash('sha1');
  hash.update(data);
  return hash.digest();
}
const buffer = Buffer.from(stringToEncrypt);
const salt = crypto.randomBytes(8);
const password = Buffer.from(encryptionKey);
const hash1 = sha1(Buffer.concat([password, salt]));
const hash2 = sha1(Buffer.concat([hash1, password, salt]));
const key = Buffer.concat([hash1, hash2]);
const iv = sha1(Buffer.concat([hash2, password, salt]));
const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
const chunks = [Buffer.from('Salted__'),salt];
chunks.push(cipher.update(buffer));
chunks.push(cipher.final());
let encryptedStuff = Buffer.concat(chunks);
```

But when I try that, the key and the iv become too long and it errors with "Invalid key length".
So, when I tried to slice it as recommended by https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6696, it does encrypt it, but openssl can't decrypt it.

Comment: What specifically is going wrong here, can you provide any more details? Also if you just need a basic encryption why don't you just use something like this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha1 ?

Comment: In this block of code, nothing is going wrong. However, I need it to be using sha1 because of mariadb. When I plug in sha1 instead of md5, then the iv becomes 20 bytes which is not allowed in createCipheriv. I also get invalid key length. When I try to slice either of those down to the appropriate lengths, it's able to encrypt it but openssl is unable to decrypt it.

Comment: Perhaps this tool will work better - https://www.npmjs.com/package/encrypter

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Unfortunately, (from https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password_options) "The implementation of crypto.createCipher() derives keys using the OpenSSL function EVP_BytesToKey with the digest algorithm set to MD5, one iteration, and no salt."  
The MD5 and no salt part are killer.

Comment: Add that to https://github.com/quorrajs/Encrypter/blob/master/Encrypter.js#L64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For details on the OpenSSL password-based encryption scheme used for `enc` namely `EVP_BytesToKey`, see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption

AES-256 in CBC mode requires 48 octets for key+IV and SHA1 output is 20 octets, so you must:

```
// do three hashes, much as you already have
hash1 = sha1(Buffer.concat([password, salt]));
hash2 = sha1(Buffer.concat([hash1, password, salt]));
hash3 = sha1(Buffer.concat([hash2, password, salt]));

// then concatenate them and split _that_ to key and IV 
total = Buffer.concat([hash1,hash2,hash3]);
key = total.slice(0,32);
iv = total.slice(32,48);
```

For md5 treating them separately worked because it happens MD5 output of 16 octets is exactly half the key size and exactly the IV size.